# Composition And Integration

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is an integrable function and let $g(x)$ be any arbitrary function defined on the interval $[a, b]$, then can anything be said about $$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(g(x))d(g(x))$$.
Also what if $g(x)$ is constant??

Comment: if g(x) is a contant $g(a)=g(b) $, yuor integral becomes 0

Comment: And what about the integral when $g(x)$ is not constant

Comment: It is unclear what you want us to tell about the integral, If you can make it more specific.....

Comment: I want to know that whether the integral exists or not and under what circumstances we can guarantee that the integral exists

Comment: well, the domain of f must have$ [g(a),g(b)]$ , else the integral wont exist finitely